# Access Modifier / Design - What to do/use for this scenario of class accessibility

Tags: c#, singleton

I've recently implemented a singleton class, and within it I've declared a static generic list of (T) class. Anyway this is my first attempt at using singleton but everything I've tried work so far.

My Question: To be consistent, I don't want the MasterSiteData to be visible to other classes except my Singleton class. I thought of maybe encapsulating both classes within a parent class which would give me new options. However I'd rather have some of the great opinions you all provide :).

```
 public sealed class Singleton
    {
        private static readonly Singleton Instance = new Singleton();

        private Singleton()
        {
        }

        public static List<MasterSiteData> MasterDetails = new List<MasterSiteData>();
    }

    public class MasterSiteData
    {
        public Guid GuidId { get; set; }
        public string Uri { get; set; }
        public int LinkNumber { get; set; }

        public MasterSiteData(Guid guid, string uri, int linknumber)
        {
            GuidId = guid;
            Uri = uri;
            LinkNumber = linknumber;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Crap! I totally forgot that I need to instantiate the MasterSiteData class to add a record to my list, therefore I really can't have it hidden, for example

```
 Singleton.MasterDetails.Add(new MasterSiteData(Guid.NewGuid(), "lol1", 1337));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an interface and make the implementation private to Singleton. (Also, don't use public fields, use properties):

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    public static List<ISiteData> Details { get; private set; }

    private Singleton()
    {
        //create new instances of MasterSiteData and add to the list
    }

    private class MasterSiteData : ISiteData
    {
        public Guid GuidID {get;set;}
        public string Uri {get;set;}
        public int LinkNumber {get;set;}

        public MasterSiteData(Guid guid, string uri, int linkNumber)
        {
            GuidID = guid;
            Uri = uri;
            LinkNumber = linkNumber;
        }
    }
}

public interface ISiteData
{
    Guid GuidID {get;set;}
    string Uri {get;set;}
    int LinkNumber {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve the accessibility level you require, you will have to declare your `MasterSiteData` class inside the `Singleton` class, and mark it's accessibility level as `private`.

For example:

```
 public class Singleton
    {
        private MasterSiteData innerClass = new MasterSiteData();

        private class MasterSiteData
        {
            // your mastersitedata class
        }
    }
```

Since the `Singleton` class effectively "owns" the `MasterSiteData` class, it can create instances of the `MasterSiteData` class itself, however no code outside of the outer `Singleton` class can access or create instances of the `MasterSiteData` type.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Implementing the above, I get a Inconsistent accessibility level error.

Comment: @Ash - An inconsistent accessibility level error usually occurs when a parameter of a method or constructor is less accessible than the method/constructor itself.  Using Rex M's advice, and using his posted code as-is, will compile fine.  Mine was merely a brief example of a private inner class.